# building a quartz cron expression

Tags: cron, quartz.net, cronexpression

Basicly I need to create complex quartz cron expression strings with .net. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

For example: Everyday, Every (2 hours, 1 minutes, 10 seconds), between 10AM - 19PM

Or at least can anyone please help me to understand cron strings to manually create them?

Of course I did my homework before asking here and looked quartz.net tutorials, several jquery plugins and some cron string generator web sites but all of them are generating or giving examples of simple crons like "on every seconds/minutes/hours", "on fridays at 11 am".

Comment: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: it doesn't provide what I want. As I said I did my homework before posting this question. By the way maybe what I want is impossible.